# How do I pass Jenkins parameters as arguments to a shell scripts read from file in Job DSL?

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

For a freestyle job, I have a bash script that is run using shell command as the build step. This script takes in a choice parameter as an argument and this works well when configuring the job via the GUI like so:

```
/path/to/script ${CHOICE_PARAMETER_VALUE}
```

However, when I am using job DSL to configure this job, I am using the "shell" function in the steps block but cannot pass an argument to it successfully. This is what I tried:

```
shell(readFileFromWorkspace('build.sh') ${CHOICE_PARAMETER_VALUE})
```

Is there a way to pass Jenkins variables as shell arguments in job DSL?

Comment: Isn't Jenkins recently based on Groovy as definition language? In this case, you would have to use string catenation of Groovy, and  I also suggest that you tag the question with _groovy_ to attract the Groovy folk. My last uses with Jenkins were still with XML as language, so I can't give an authoritative answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just asked a colleague and apparently, there is no need to do what I was intending to do. Jenkins environment variables (and parameters) can be referenced by the called shell script, hence there is no need to specifically pass the parameters/variables as arguments.

Basically, I can do this in my `build.sh` script:

```
echo ${CHOICE_PARAMETER_VALUE}
```

I have tested this and it works fine!!!

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted, because it really works. :) Thanks.